# CakePHP Problem disabling debug in Controller action

Tags: cakephp

Can someone help me work out just what I happening here.

I have an ajax function on my controller, when it returns the json it flags up some undefined variable notices even though I have `Configure::write('debug', 0)` at the top of the function.

Outputting `Configure::read("debug")` in the function shows zero correctly.

If I change the debug to 0 in the core.php the messages disappear however.

Does anyone know why I may still be getting notices? I really can't think where its going wrong

Thanks

Comment: Is this ajax function calling a method in a different controller? Where are the errors being displayed?

Comment: No the ajax only calls the Model::find. The errors along with a full debug are output before the json. ie Notice (8): Undefined variable: profession [APP\controllers\calendar_events_controller.php, line 112]

Comment: Looks to me like it's trying to execute the code at line 122 before you turn off the debug. Why don't you fix that undefined variable first? [Not the same Leo as the OP]

Comment: I have fixed the undefined variable and it works fine but why show I get Notices anyway with debug set to zero? Thats what concerns me.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your code, but I'd suggest that the error occurs before your ajaxMethod turns off debug. As you pointed out, when debug==0 in core.php the error messages disappear. The ajaxMethod is overriding the core setting for that method only. Before and after ajaxMethod, debug is whatever it is set to in core.php. Try outputting the debug level before you set it - preferably in the calling method and also before line 122. That might give you a better picture of what is happening.

Comment: I did output it, in firebug the response was 0 before the JSON was output via json_encode and after it! Thats the mystery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally put this in the `beforeFilter` function of my `app_controller.php` file:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

See if that helps.